# Cannot establish a connection to orientdb using jdbc driver?

Tags: jdbc, netbeans, orientdb, nosql

I'm newbie to the orientdb, I'm using netbeans's (add new connection wizard) to add a connection to the orientdb, I used orientdb-jdbc-2.0.2-all.jar as a jdbc driver, but I got the following error after clicking on test connection

[Snapshot of the error](http://s30.postimg.org/lwqldy0pd/Untitled.png)

I made sure that the database is connected and everything is right, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL should be `jdbc:orient:remote:localhost/Sensor_Data`

Look at the documentation: http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb-jdbc.wiki/Home.html#first-get-a-connection.

Answer (score 0):

the problem should be in the connection port. You are using 2480 (HTTP port) instead of 2424 (binary protocol).

Comment: Same Error...
I used this url >> jdbc:orient://localhost:2424/Sensor_Data